# Extract correct strings from a MongoDB nested hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, mongodb, hash

I am new to Ruby and need to access a MongoDB database and return some info from a search. So far I can get the required record but I am having difficulty extracting the info from the nested hash that is returned.

```
hash = {"Skills"  => [{"_id" => 200, "description" => "Running"}, {"_id" => 201, "description" => "Jumping"}]}
```

This is the hash that is returned. I can access the required hash but cannot seem to extract just the "Running" and "Jumping" strings I require.

I have tried

```
puts hash["Skills"]
```

but I just get:

```
{"_id"=>200, "description"=>"Running"}
{"_id"=>201, "description"=>"Jumping"}
```

What I need returned is:

```
"Running"
"Jumping"
```

I would have thought that the following would have worked:

```
puts hash["Skills"]["Description"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look carefully, the `Skills` key of your hash is an array and not another hash. Therefore, you could achieve your solution by using [`Array#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
hash['Skills'].map { |s| s['description'] }
# => ["Running", "Jumping"]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have not used the map method before so this opens up a number of possibilities going forward,

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out now. I Just realised while doing the washing up that it was of course an array. I will now explore Davids more elegant answer

```
hash["skills"].each do |h|
    puts h["description"]
end


Running
Jumping
```